# multiple sessions on heidiSQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, session, heidisql

I'm using HeidiSQL 12.3.0.6589 and I have a session called "api_teste", with a database inside it that contains various information. However, I have to create another session, as I was asked to do a separate service and when creating this other session, the data contained within the "api_teste" session automatically goes into it, and when I make changes, it changes in both sessions, it would have how to create different sessions with different databases on the same computer?

Comment: Are "sessions" connections? Connections have a default database, but can access other database if the user has permission. Are you after two database. Your wording isn't clear enough to describe what your problem actually is. Go back to basics and edit your question with steps taken, results observed, and expected results.

Comment: Yes, "sessions" are connections. How can I make the user access only one specific one?